# Appcelerator Titanium Push Notification for Android Emulator?

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator-mobile

The Source code  [from](https://github.com/IGx89/titanium-c2dm) the link downloaded and  i  Imported as My Project In Titanium(1.8.1) and Registered in C2DM Server after Compiling it Runtime Error like in Emulator " Uncaught Error:Requested Module Not Found com.findlaw.titanium.c2dm".If anyone knows tell me for Proper Push Notification to run an Emulator(I have Installed Android Market in an Emulator) and am using Windows 7.thank u

Comment: i am not getting the project path and can not getting executed in titanium of that project which is available in githib. Please suggest me how can i use that.

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy u can download project from above link (from) and download as a zip file then import to your workspace it will work

Answer (score 1):

The Push Notifications can be set to Actual Devices Only. Install your App in real phone and test this.

If you added extra modules for registering and receiving push notifications, you have to add that module in **tiapp.xml**

```
 <module version="0.1">ti.tvout</module>
```

Comment: Hi Sadeshkumar did u implemented Push notification in Appcelerator Titanium.If yes Please Guide me!!.I had spend many days.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder why you can't send push notifications to your emulator? They have a network connection and they should have a connection to the app market. It seems like a big inconvenience to have to actually deploy a build to a real phone when testing push.